# Migrating dates in the same timezone: convert arguments to subfields?

Tags: migrations, datetime

I have a migration that is successful except for the timezone.

```
$this->addFieldMapping('dest_date', 'source_date');
```

For some reason the above code causes a timezone conversion to happen between the source date and the destination timezone. The migration seems to assume the source is in UTC and needs converted to Chicago time, giving me a result that's six hours later than it should be. The source date is in fact from the same timezone, so I want to avoid converting it.

```
$this->addFieldMapping('dest_date', 'source_date')
  ->arguments(DateMigrateFieldHandler::arguments('America/Chicago', 'America/Chicago'));
```

The above code works perfectly, but when I run my migration I get this error:

> The field mapping arguments() method is now deprecated - please use subfield notation instead.

However when I try to use subfield notation, I end up with the same problem again that I did when I had no arguments/subfields at all:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('dest_date', 'source_date');
$this->addFieldMapping('dest_date:timezone', 'source_date:timezone');
```

The above code doesn't seem to help at all, (edit: This is not surprising, as my field doesn't seem to have "timezone" as a subfield.) and the migration still seems to assume the source is in UTC and needs converted to Chicago time.

How do I convert my arguments to subfield notation without breaking them?

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('dest_date:timezone')
->defaultValue('America/Chicago');
```

Comment: This works, but since 7.x-2.5 (?) Migrate has also supported `->addFieldMapping('dest_date', 'source_date')->arguments(array("timezone" => "..."))`.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the same thing for hours before caving in and hacking the date module a teensy little bit :-)

My datefields are of the type "datetime" so I had to insert a timezone variable on line 158 of the date.migrate.inc file of the date module - like this:

```
        case 'datetime':
      // YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.
      $timezone = 'Europe/Copenhagen'; #add this line
      $from = format_date($from, 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $timezone);
      if ($to) {
        $to = format_date($to, 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $timezone);
      }
      break;
```

You can just remove it after migration. I would love a better solution - I thought of extending the DateMigrateFieldHandler class, but that just gave me double dates :-/

Hope this helps

Comment: so I get why your solution would work and looks like a trivial hack, have an upvote. Although, I wonder if adding a pseudo-field in `prepareRow` to store the old value and then `prepare` and just setting the new date value to the old value (you're in the same timezone) ...... would be easier. I see posts like this and think people dont want to implement any of the Migration methods in their classes (and just try to everything via field Mappings). See: https://www.drupal.org/node/1132582

Comment: again, I would love to fix this "the proper way", and I did try various methods using both preparerow and prepare to no avail. If there is some way to alter DateMigrateFieldHandler to use the correct timezone I have yet to find it.